# xxx is not a function, inside a for

Tags: javascript

The error:
Menu.js:31 Uncaught TypeError: bubble.render is not a function

It happens into this code:

```
function Menu() {
    this.bubbles = [];
    this.bubbles.push(new MenuBubble("Etudiants",FSMEnum.ETUDIANTS));
    this.bubbles.push(new MenuBubble("Sujets",FSMEnum.SUJETS));
    this.bubbles.push(new MenuBubble("Valider",FSMEnum.VALIDATE));
    this.bubbles.push(new MenuBubble("Choix",FSMEnum.MATCH));

    this.render = function(x,y,w,h) {
        ctx.fillStyle = '#555555';
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);

        var i=0;
        for(bubble in this.bubbles)
        {
            bubble.render(x+(w/2), y+((h/6)*(i+1))); // Here's the error 1
            i++;
        }
    };

    this.getBubbles = function() {
        return this.bubbles;
    };

}
```

and this one:

```
function MenuBubble(name,state) {

    this.name = name;
    this.state = state;

    this.render = function(x,y) {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#003300';
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();


    };


    this.clicked = function() {
        FSM.state = this.state;
    };


}
```

The two bits of code above are in different files, which are included in the correct order (MenuBubble, and then Menu).

Those 2 codes are ran inside a main, which poses no problem.

In the main i can run code like:

```
Menu.getBubbles().forEach(function(element) {
        if (true) {
            alert('clicked a bubble');
            this.clicked(); // Here's the error 2
        }
    });
```

It runs perfectly, but is not calling any functions from the bubble for some reasons.

Edit: to clarify, i meant that the alert showed (if the clicked thing is commented, it shows 4 times, as i have instanciated 4 bubbles in my menu)

In the second case calling this.clicked() or simply clicked() doesnt work in either way.

Is there something i'm missing with object methods?

Main.js: http://pastebin.com/BmTiDbFD

Index.html: http://pastebin.com/CfmYu5eJ

Comment: Are you trying to recursively call `this.render()`?

Comment: Within the menu, each time I render, I call the MenuBubble's render alongside the menu rendering. It have been answered below :)

Comment: No. The recursive calls to `bubble.render(x+(w/2), y+((h/6)*(i+1)))` creates an infinite loop https://jsfiddle.net/mqdnx4w6/

Comment: I don't see how, and the code is compiling correctly/ have a good behaviour. Frame start => Menu calls render => Bubble's render are called, but they dont call anything => back to menu render => frame end

Comment: Then must be missing something, here. Calling `that.render()` at jsfiddle results in loop that does not have a conclusion.

Comment: Ooooh i see, in your case the bubble is not an object, in mine it is, and that objets have its own render code. Which is therefore why i don't call `that.render()` but `bubble.render()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
for(bubble in this.bubbles)
```

Isn't doing what you think it is. For each loops in JS go through indexes, not items.

```
for(index in this.bubbles) {
  var bubble = this.bubbles[index];
  ...
```

is what you want

Comment: Thanks! Coming from other languages, i wouldn't have guessed that in days! Validating in 3 mins!

Comment: While your solution is correct, your explanation is not at all correct. for/in loops are meant to iterate objects and enumerate that object's properties. The enumeration variable returns the property name as a string and that name can be passed into the object to return the value of that property. for loops that count use numeric indexes and are meant for use on arrays and array-like objects. They only enumerate the elements of the array and not all non-index properties. The correct way to do this, since an array is being iterated, would be to use accounting loop.

Comment: Thanks, I now understand the comment that has been made below! Accounting loop is a for/of?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. It's not accounting, it's a counting -- just a normal loop that counts : for(var i = 0; ...

Answer (score 2):

[image: Maybe that's why]

Maybe that's why, `bubble` is just the index.

UPDATE: indexes are numbers, `i` or `bubble` is not the index. Because for/in enumerates properties, not indexes. So `typeof i` will be `string` but not `number`

Comment: Thanks! I've been given the same answer a few seconds earlier, but still thanks for the time spent!

Comment: Not true (although the console makes it look that way). for/in enumerates properties, not indexes. Change your log to: typeof i and you will see string. Indexes are numbers. Use a regular counting for loop and try it. You'll get number.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right, I didn't expect their are difference between the properties and indexes. Thanks again!

Comment: The difference is more than just data types. Using for/in on an array will loop over all properties of the array (including ones that don't store array elements, like length). With arrays, use a counting loop so you are truly using indexes and you will only be able to retrieve elements of the array, not properties.

Answer (score 1):

For the 'this.clicked() scenario:

replace 'this.clicked()' with 'element.clicked()'

Comment: Thanks! is the "element" thing something commonly returned? Just by instinct i'd name many things "element", but seeing this it can conflict pretty easily no?

Comment: You can name it whatever you like. If another variable from a higher scope shares the same name you will shadow it. (won't be able to access the parent scope variable anymore) so best to avoid common names. Generally just call it what it is, i.e  an instance of MenuBubble, 'menuBubble'

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable to reference `this`, substitute `for..of` loop for `for..in` loop

```js
function Menu() {
    this.bubbles = [];
    this.bubbles.push(10);
    this.bubbles.push(20);
    this.bubbles.push(30);
    this.bubbles.push(40);
    var that = this;
    this.render = function(prop) {
        console.log(prop || "first call")
        for(bubble of this.bubbles)
        {
            console.log(bubble); // Here's the error 1
        }
    };

    this.getBubbles = function() {
        return this.bubbles;
    };

}

var g = new Menu();
g.render()
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but i do not understand the maneuver behind that. I've just been told that the for..in "returns" an index, does the for..of navigate the different objects? And i do not understant the var that = this; too actually, does it have any usage?

Comment: `for..of` loop will iterate the elements of the array itself, instead of the indexes of the array. `that = this` was to maintain of reference to `this` inside `for..of` loop, though recursively calling `that.render()`, that is `that.render(x+(w/2), y+((h/6)*(i+1)))`, within `for..in` or `for..of` loop leads to an infinite loop, omitted from stacksnippets

Comment: No, for/in does NOT return an index. As I pointed out, that's what a regular counting loop iterates with and that's what you should be using sing you have a basic array.

Comment: @ScottMarcus _"No, for/in does NOT return an index."_ Not sure what you mean?

Comment: An index is  non-negative integer. for/in loops enumerate all properties of an object. The properties are ALWAYS strings. Regular counting loops return indexes and are for use in arrays, as they only enumerate the array element and not all the array properties.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Perhaps worded _"instead of the indexes of the array"_ inappropriately. Properties would be the appropriate term. `for..of` loop iterates values of iterable, without need to access the actual value of the element of the array using both the original array and the current property which would be case using `for..in` loop.

Comment: Yes, I understand for/of and that's fine here. But, it's important to understand indexes vs. properties because for/in iterates all properties (not just array elements) and so it shouldn't be used on arrays. But, FYI my comments here were in response to @Morgan Fouque not you.